# room-tone sound library help

Tags: sound-libraries, room

I am looking for a sound library with different room tone recordings. If you can recommend some sites I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple good ones to check:

http://rabbitearsaudio.com/rea013-bridgett-tones/

Comment: Is it just me or do many of the ones in this set sound hissy?  I personally find many of them not clean enough of high frequency grain to be useful, or I have to EQ to get what I want.  I'll take any roomtone I can get - although this set felt a little disappointing to me in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Guido Helbling has some pretty extensive libraries too: https://www.soundeffects.ch/en/sound-libraries/room-tones/

Comment: Thank you Shaun. The Library can be found at: https://www.soundeffects.ch/en/sound-libraries/soundeffects.ch-products/roomtones-v01-sound-library.php Also there is a set of Impulse Responses included in the library: https://www.soundeffects.ch/en/sound-libraries/soundeffects.ch-products/ir1-impulse-response-set.php . All the tracks are new and fresh and from stereo up to Auro 3D! Have a look at my site, also I'm happy to answer questions, best

Answer (score 0):

Sound Collectors Club are doing a new theme based on room tones. You might want to check it out. You'll have to contribute first to the library yourself though but could be well worth it.

http://thesoundcollectorsclub.com/2013/08/12/first-new-theme-for-2013-14/